# htaccess reverts me back to wampserver dashboard

Tags: .htaccess

I am not a star with htaccess, so by all means please correct where needed. I a trying to set up seo friendly URLs for my project, but I am getting contstantly reverted to my dashboard of the wampserver, so the index file of wamp when i try to open the site in url format.

The intended url = http://localhost/darktiderising/profile/character/1/edit/

in the www/darktiderising/ folder i added the following htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /darktiderising/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ /index.php?module=$1&section=$2&characterid=$3&form=$4 [L,QSA]
```

I sadly dont see what i am doing wrong.

Before you ask, AllowOverride All is active in the httpd.conf, and I did check that the rewrite-module was active.

Comment: Shouldn't it be just index.php instead of /index.php? I haven't tried it, but I think that /index.php could redirect you to your www/index.php, which could be consistent with the symptoms you are describing (www/index.php could be the dashboard of your wamp install)

Comment: @JakubJudas geezus, i feel so stupid by not seeing the first slash before the index.php ... thanks!